# Echo JSON Twitter API (1.1) PHP

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am trying to display coordinates from Twitter Search API 1.1 (GET).

I can output the entire JSON file after encoding the tweets - http://pastebin.com/bKLye2an

```
$search = str_replace("#", "%23", $search); 
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=".$search."&count=".$notweets);

$json = json_encode($tweets);
```

However, in PHP I used the following codes to display the coordinates and nothing appears.

```
 foreach ($json['statuses'] as $key => $value)
{
foreach ($json['coordinates']['coordinates'] as $key => $value)
{
echo "$key: $value\n";
};
};
```

As far as I can see, the structure is statuses-coordinates-coordinates for geo.

How do I echo coordinates (if present) for all tweets in search).

Comment: You do not require a second foreach loop. Just try with `$value['coordinates'];`.

Comment: I removed the 2nd loop - http://pastebin.com/8i4tUucT - still same issue - blank output.

Comment: First loop will be of `$json['statuses']` only and not of `$json['coordinates']['coordinates']`.

Comment: as rikesh has said, `$value['coordinates']` has no more child arrays, its alone already. and by the way, your sample json on coordinates is **`null`**

Comment: Here is my full code (minus the keys and tokens): http://pastebin.com/7LUAZuqx Still outputting nothing

Comment: a simple `foreach($json['statuses'] as $key => $value) {  var_dump($value['coordinates']); }` is enough. in your example json, `coordinates` is **`null`**. so obviously its null (you will get empty)

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample json string, a simple foreach is enough. Consider this example:

```
$json_string = '{"statuses":[{"metadata":{"result_type":"recent","iso_language_code":"en"},"created_at":"Mon Jun 16 08:35:18 +0000 2014","id":478455763761786880,"id_str":"478455763761786880","text":"Later go shop at cold storage. LOLOL","source":"Twitter for Android<\/a>","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":559622523,"id_str":"559622523","name":"AhYong","screen_name":"likeasomebodeh","location":"To each and every road.","description":"Fun-Sized \/ CE1404N \/ BARVENGERS \/ Sagittarian \/ Sixth Gun \/ Drummer - Wannabe","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/PFSXy17655","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/PFSXy17655","expanded_url":"http:\/\/ask.fm\/Ah_Yong","display_url":"ask.fm\/Ah_Yong","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":329,"friends_count":444,"listed_count":1,"created_at":"Sat Apr 21 13:30:49 +0000 2012","favourites_count":4930,"utc_offset":28800,"time_zone":"Beijing","geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":33116,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"131516","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/459318345003593728\/mhjxKipm_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/459318345003593728\/mhjxKipm_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/559622523\/1401358655","profile_link_color":"009999","profile_sidebar_border_color":"EEEEEE","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EFEFEF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"lang":"en"}],"search_metadata":{"completed_in":0.016,"max_id":478455763761786880,"max_id_str":"478455763761786880","next_results":"?max_id=478455763761786879&q=flu%20OR%20cold%20OR%20%23flu%20OR%20%23cold%20OR%20%23snot%20OR%20%23ill&count=1&include_entities=1","query":"flu+OR+cold+OR+%23flu+OR+%23cold+OR+%23snot+OR+%23ill","refresh_url":"?since_id=478455763761786880&q=flu%20OR%20cold%20OR%20%23flu%20OR%20%23cold%20OR%20%23snot%20OR%20%23ill&include_entities=1","count":1,"since_id":0,"since_id_str":"0"}}';
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);
foreach($json['statuses'] as $key => $json_values) {
    if(isset($json_values['coordinates']) && !empty($json_values['coordinates'])) {
        // continue your processes if key exists and not empty
    }

}
```

> Important Note: In your given json, take note, your `coordinates` is **`null`**

Comment: I tried the above http://pastebin.com/W5ghUiMS
My output is now "ArrayArrayArray"

Comment: @CodyRaspien could you please `var_export($json2)`. it seems your json string example and the one that you are using on your code does not match.